# Project 'net5.csproj' targets 'net5.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'

Tags: .net-5

I am trying to reference .net5 class library to .net framework 4.6.1 project, Can .net 5.0 is capable of referencing the class library to .net framework 4.6.1 project

Comment: this is not possible, use .netstandard 2.0 project as shared project

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, the behavior you are seeing has been normal for many years. For example, a 4.5 project cannot reference a 4.6 project. If you change your 4.6.1 project to 5.0, however, I would predict it will compile just fine without any problems.

Comment: Yes you are right but is there any way, I am just confused on  microsoft article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five

Comment: If you want to make it a class library, look into targeting `netstandard1.3` (as an example) instead of `net5.0`. Your 4.6.1 framework project should be able to reference a .NET Standard 1.3 project.

Comment: It looks like omajid has a good solution. After (just now) looking at "netstandard" I think what he suggested is what I would do, if I didn't want to upgrade the 4.6.1 project to 5.0

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, I needed to repair the .Net SDK. Once computer restarted afterwards, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the issue was that I selected "Class Library" instead of "Class Library (.Net Framework)" when creating the project.